# How difficult is to decompile C++ file?

Tags: c++, android, ios

I am writing an Android app with AES encryption and I am going to save AES key as a string to a C++ file with extension `.cpp`.

I am also going to create an iOS app which will use the same AES key. Is it possible to save the key in C++ file in iOS? 
How difficult would it be to decompile the C++ file and read the key?

Here is the C++ file from Android:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string>

extern "C"
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_android_app_aesKeyFromJNI(JNIEnv *env, jobject /* this */) {
    std::string secret = "somesecretkey";
    return env->NewStringUTF(secret.c_str());
}
```

Comment: A plain ascii string is anything but secret.

Comment: Any reason not to use the Android keystore system which is explicitly made for this purpose?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52437492/214671

Comment: No need to decompile. There is a piece of software called "strings" (typically installed or available to unixen like Linux and Mac OS) that will dump all strings in your app. All I have to do is to test the strings one-by-one until I find the correct secret key. Obviously I'd skip strings like "Thank You." and "Login:"

Comment: You don't talk about *compiling* this C++ file anywhere.  The C++ file already *is* plain text.  I think you're talking about distributing an object file or library compiled from this `.cpp`, but that's not what you wrote in the question, you just keep talking about the C++ source.

Comment: @slebetman Next time I shall make my keys "Thank You." or "Login:" and they will be safe!

Comment: There are fundamental security problems with this approach to cryptography extending far beyond how easily a string can be extracted from an executable (however obfuscated). This is almost the exact purpose of asymmetric cryptography, and systems based on it such as TLS. Use a library! Possibly ask on https://security.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 20):

**Not hard enough!**

First of all, if you save the key as a non-encrypted string, a simple `strings` command will find it and IDA x-ref will even show the reverser where it's used.
If you save the key encrypted, a simple breakpoint will let them see the decrypted password. (or understanding the decryption algorithm).

Comment: "or understanding the decryption algorithm"
Shouldn't be understanding the algorithm be irrelevant to breaking it?
At least in well-designed encryption I thought that was kind of a design standard

Comment: @Hobbamok My point was that if you return the secret, you need to decrypt it. The algorithm and password for the decryption will be written. A reverser could simply extract those and decrypt yhe original secret

Answer (score 12):

A plain text string like this will be visible by looking at the file in a hex editor (like `hte` or a viewer like `xxd` or `od`) or with the [Sysinternals `strings`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/strings) command or with [`strings(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strings.1.html) on a Linux/FreeBSD etc, for example. Most reverse engineering tools have a separate view for strings, because those are usually exceptionally useful to reverse engineers. Amirag already pointed that out for IDA.

In terms of Android that C++ file is likely going to end up as a shared object in ELF file format. These are binary files with a known structure. Simply by looking at the exported functions/symbols, it will be trivial to find the "secret". Even if you were to obfuscate this further, it would still not help. Obfuscation is [security through obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity). It's not *actual security*. So even writing that string as some xor-ed array of bytes or using the [Caesar cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher) will add no tangible protection if that's the goal.

Furthermore you should **never ever** include the private key in code that ends up with the user. The reason why it's called a secret is because it should be *kept secret*. Just "mangling" the representation of this secret with a compiler isn't going to help at all.

If it's a secret the user shouldn't see, this belongs on the server-side or into a HSM (hardware security module), but *not* on the user's machine in *any* form. There is no other way to reconcile *mistrusting* the user and at the same time placing "secrets" into the user's hands. It's the fundamental conundrum of software protection mechanisms also.

Comment: Can a user see the string if they open the file in Notepad? Because ten-year-olds will try that.

Comment: @Robyn: In theory, yes. However, if you mean Windows Notepad, that has typically huge problems with Unix line breaks and besides, there's no telling how many line breaks there are anyway in a binary. So the text may appear in one long line. That said, if your ten-year-old knows to turn it on, they can make use of the Word Wrap feature to mitigate that problem to some extent.